# ¿Cómo seleccionar con Jquery un ID dentro de una etiqueta ej: body?

Tags: jquery, selectores

tengo un elemento con el ID: #MyID que se encuentra en el Body y tengo que seleccionarla por el uso de un Plugin por ejemplo en el CSS:

```
body #MyId {
  display: none;
}
```

Entonces en el archivo .js tengo que cambiar el display a "block" y lo intento con el siguiente código pero no me funciona:

```
$("body #fullpage").css("display", "block");
```

¿me podrían por favor indicar la forma correcta de selección y cual es mi error?

De antemano muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la instrucción:
`$('body #fullpage').show();` Esto cambia directamente a `display block`.

Para ocultar utilizas: `.hide()`

Aunque no veo el por qué utilizar `body`. Pues si es un `id`, el nombre debe ser único.

Comment: Por alguna razón con solo el ID no me lo reconoce en el CSS y no se si lo seleccione bien como lo hago en el Jquery pero no lo muestra.